# How can I retrieve the value by parsing my XML file

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing

I'm trying to gather the data from an XML file and add to an array. The data looks something like this..

```
<Placemark>
<name><![CDATA[Kingsway (Start)]]></name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
<TimeStamp><when>2014-04-30T17:03:28.681Z</when></TimeStamp>
<styleUrl>#start</styleUrl>
<Point>
<coordinates>-1.408894,52.13977,176.0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark id="tour">
<name><![CDATA[Kingsway]]></name>
<description><![CDATA[]]></description>
<styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="type"><value><![CDATA[running]]></value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
<gx:MultiTrack>
<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
<gx:interpolate>1</gx:interpolate>
<gx:Track>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:28.681Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.408894 52.13977 176.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:31.071Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.407839 52.139166 174.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:32.070Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.407486 52.138963 175.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:33.073Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.407142 52.138755 174.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:34.073Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.406805 52.138555 173.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:35.073Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.40663 52.138441 173.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:36.601Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.405929 52.138027 172.0</gx:coord>
<when>2014-04-30T17:03:37.601Z</when>
<gx:coord>-1.405574 52.137817 172.0</gx:coord>
```

I'm only interested in the values following the tag gx:coord, so I'm parsing the file using the code below.

```
- (void)loadMap:(NSInteger)selJourney
{
    NSString *journey = @"KML_Sample";
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:journey ofType:@"kml"];
    [self parseXMLFile:path];
}

- (void)parseXMLFile:(NSString *)pathToFile
{
    NSXMLParser *addressParser;

    [myParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [myParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [myParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
    myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [myParser setDelegate:self];
    [myParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [myParser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:   (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"gx:coord"] ) {
        polylineList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}
```

When the parser method runs and it finds the right elementName I want to retrieve the string data after the tag and add it to my NSMutableArray polylineList.
The other parameters in parser all return nil so am I missing something?

Comment: in your didStartElement method you allocate a whole new array each time it's called, and you never ever add anything to any arrays. Seems like you only want to allocate an array in one place, and then add to that array each time you find a gx:coord element! Try that and re-post.

Comment: Yes I realise that, maybe I should have left that line out. The whole point is that I want to know (as I said in my question), how can I retrieve the value from this method

Comment: do not use these kind of words. please remove these comments. thanks. +1 for nice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself using the method below

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ((addRec) && (![string isEqualToString:@"\n"]))
    {
        NSArray *tmpArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:string, nil];
        if (polylineList.count > 0)
            [polylineList addObject:string];
        else
            polylineList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tmpArray];
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful to those who are using KML, MapKit or just parsing XML.